# findOne() doesn't work - is something wrong with my syntax?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongojs

Db creation:

```
var mongojs = require('mongojs');
var db = mongojs('rodrigo-contatos', ['rodrigo-contatos']);
```

i'm trying to do a search in database with this code, using findOne from mongojs, that is the code:

```
app.get('/detalhesContato/:id', function(req, res){
var id = req.params.id;
console.log(id);
db.contatos.findOne({_id: mongojs.ObjectId(id)}, function(err, doc)    {
 console.log(err);
  res.json(doc);

});
```

`console.log(id)` the id is correct but findOne is not working no matter what i do ;(.

"567a16ba28dee028f4a8ad78 <-- console log from id

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'findOne' of undefined at
>   /Users/Michel/Documents/AngularProjects/RodrigoBranasListaTelefonica/server.js:48:12"

Comment: ok i made it can you see?

Comment: The issue is contatos is undefined. Try a console.log(db) and you will see there is no contatos. I've never used mongo in the way you are using it but here is a guess: db['rodrigo-contatos'].findOne

Comment: console log(db) returned db without problem

Answer (score 0):

With [mongojs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongojs), you need to explicitly identify the collections you want to access as properties of `db` when you call `mongojs` to create your `db` object. So because you're trying to access the `contatos` collection, that name needs to be provided to your `mongojs` call in the second (array of strings) parameter:

```
var db = mongojs('rodrigo-contatos', ['contatos']);
```

Or you can just skip the short-cut access from `db` and get the collection later:

```
var contatos = db.collection('contatos');
contatos.findOne(...);
```

Comment: humm it's impossible to maintain connection with all the database at once?

Comment: this code works anyway without identifying: db.collection('contatos').find(function(err, docs){
 console.log(docs);
 res.json(docs);
});

Answer (score 0):

Ok problem solved you need to identify collection when creating db connection.
Interesting that was only necessary for findOne() with find() was working just fine this way:

```
var db = mongojs('rodrigo-contatos', ['rodrigo-contatos']);
```

but like this, work like charm with findOne():

```
 var db = mongojs('rodrigo-contatos', ['contatos']);
```